# setting y-axis to feet inches in C# using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion's SFChart controls for Xamarin Forms and I am trying to plot data in feet inches using a StackingColumnSeries (this data represents the height of different fluid types within a container). The data source is in inches. Example code is below:

```
<chart:SfChart.Series>
    <chart:StackingColumnSeries
        Width="0.5"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ContainerLevels}" 
        XBindingPath="Name" YBindingPath="Level1"
        EnableTooltip="True">
</chart:StackingColumnSeries>
```

Here `TankLevels` is an observable collection that contains fluid levels in inches. `Level1` refers to the level of the first fluid in inches. `Name` is the name of the container.

How can I manipulate the `Level1` data source (currently decimal) so that the y-axis will display in feet inches?

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/130779/value-converter-on-datetime-axis-in-sfchart

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/133198/funnel-chart-label-string-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have analyzed your query and we like to let you know that our numerical axis will show the values bound to the series and do not have any numerical conversion built in. So, we recommend you to convert the inches to feet as like in below code snippet and bound feet value directly to the ChartSeries.

```
private void ConvertInchesTofeet(ObservableCollection<Model> containerLevels)
{
   for(int i = 0; i< containerLevels.Count; i++)
   {
   ContainerLevels[i].Level1 = containerLevels[i].Level1 / 12;
   }
}
```

To show the value in inches, you can use tooltip. We have prepared a sample based on this and it can be downloaded from the below link.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/221998/ze/221998_sample858964026.zip)

Note – I work for Syncfusion.